# Separate fraction in two with the denominator

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations

I have this problem:

$\frac{a}{5} + \frac{b}{8} = \frac{31}{40}$

I now the answer is $a=2$ and $b=3$.

I tried doing a table with simple formula:

$(a*8) + (b*5)= 31$

So, I do the table:

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
  a\backslash b& 1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 7 \\
  \hline
  1& 13& 18& 23& 28& 33& 38& 43  \\
  2& 21& 26& \color{green}{\mathbf{31}}& 36& 41& 46& 51  \\
  3& 29& 34& 39& 44& 49& 54& 59 \\
  4& 37& 42& 47& 52& 57& 62& 67 \\
\end{array}

But I think maybe have another method without brute force.

How I can solve this problem with the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem of finding integer solutions to $8a + 5b = 31$ is an example of a [linear diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Linear_Diophantine_equations).  There are several well known approaches, here's one.

First, note that $\gcd(5,8) = 1$.  So, begin by solving $8a + 5b = 1$.  A systematic way to do so is with the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).  In particular, we find that
$$
8 = (2)5 - 2, \qquad 
5 = (2)2 + 1 \implies\\
1 = 5 - (2)2 = 5-(2)[(2)5 - 8] = (2)8 + (-3)5
$$
so, $a = 2$ and $b = -3$ solves $8a + 5b = 1$.

So, if we now take $a = 2 \cdot 31$ and $b = -3 \cdot 31$, we have a solution to $8a + 5b = 31$.  That is, $a = 62,b = -93$ is one solution to the equation we started with.

From there, we can deduce that the general solution will be
$$
a = 62 - 5n, \quad
b = -93 + 8n, \quad n \in \Bbb Z
$$
Setting $n = 12$, we get the solution with the lowest positive value of $a$, namely
$$
a = 2, \quad b = 3
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that $a,b$ are positive integers (as it seems you do), then you can write $$5b=31-8a.$$

That means $31-8a$ has to be $\geq 0$, or $a\leq 3$. So you are just left to try $a=1,2,3$. Only $a=2$ gives an integer value of $b$.

Comment: Yes! I assume a,b are positive. And your formula is better with less brute force. But you think there is a one or two formulas to have the answers? Because in other case like:  (a/5) + (b/8) = 3621/40. The answer is: a=232, b=353. Can be too long try 1,2,3,4...

Comment: In your new example, there are a lot of answers besides the one you gave. For example, $a=227,b=361$ is also an answer. All integer answers can be written as $a=232+5k,b=353-8k$ for any integer $k$.

Comment: Aham! So the minimun values of can hold the oparation is: is $a = 2, b = 721$ and $a = 452, b = 1$, but in first instance you need use brute force with: $5b = 3621 - 8a$ ?

Comment: You can start with any solution. Say you find $a=2,b=721$. Then all integer solutions can be written as $a=2+5k$ and $b=721-8k$ for any integer $k$.

Comment: And that means necessarily have to make more thant 1000 attempts to find the first solution, and if the numbers grow the attemps grow too D: